# getting text from dynamically created edittext into a button android java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created dynamically edittext on my android application like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        final EditText[] Et = new EditText[10];
        int prevTextViewId = 0;
        int add = 0;
        int add1 = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {

            Et[a] = new EditText(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = 25;
            param.topMargin = (a + 1) * (100 + add1);
            Et[a].setPadding(5, 23, 5, 5);
            Et[a].setLayoutParams(param);
            Et[a].setSingleLine(false);
            Et[a].setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            Et[a].setWidth(280);
            Et[a].getText().toString();
            layout.addView(Et[a]);
            add = add + 25;
            add1 = add1 + 15;
        }
}
```

And I want to get text from dynamically created edittext into a button like below:

```
btn_doneAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_doneAnswer);
        btn_doneAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {
                        Et[a] = new EditText(this);
                        String text += Et[a].getText().toString();
                    }
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Intent i_backToAddItem = new Intent(
                            AnswerActivityMultiText.this,
                            QuestionActivityDynamic.class);
                    bundle.putString("text", text);
                    bundle.putString("MultiQues", MultiQues);
                    i_backToAddItem.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i_backToAddItem);

            }
        });
```

But I am getting error below in the button onclick method at this line `Et[a] = new EditText(this);`:

```
The constructor EditText(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined
```

another below error at this line `+=` in the button onclick method:

```
Syntax error on token "+=", = expected
```

Kindly suggest me how I am getting text from dynamically created edittext into a button.

Waiting for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to initialize the EditText again in the onClick. You should directly use the EditText object to get the text. So the line

```
Et[a] = new EditText(this);
```

is not required at all!

And for the error with '+=' operator, you are declaring the string and using the operator(+=) in one line. you have to split up the the declaration part out of the for loop and then use '+='. Here's the complete code :

```
btn_doneAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_doneAnswer);
    btn_doneAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String text;
               for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {
                    text += Et[a].getText().toString();
                }
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Intent i_backToAddItem = new Intent(
                        AnswerActivityMultiText.this,
                        QuestionActivityDynamic.class);
                bundle.putString("text", text);
                bundle.putString("MultiQues", MultiQues);
                i_backToAddItem.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i_backToAddItem);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in this lines:

```
for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {
    Et[a] = new EditText(this);
    String text += Et[a].getText().toString();
}
```

In this line:

```
Et[a] = new EditText(this);
```

**this** is the onClickListener object, you must have class.this (where class is the class name of file that this code is created).

In this other line:

```
String text += Et[a].getText().toString();
```

You always create a new String, and instead of created, you make an add. It is a Java concept fail.

You must do this:

```
String text = "";
for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {
    Et[a] = new EditText(class_name.this);
    text += Et[a].getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error `Syntax error on token "{", Expression expected after this token` at this line `for (int a = 0; a < Arr.length; a++) {` .

Comment: So you have some brackets bad closed

Comment: No, I have put your piece of code as it is, if I remove it everything is fine.kindly suggest me,

Comment: can u explain why we have to initialize the EditText objects again in the onClick Method? and in [a] = new EditText(this); `[a]` is incorrect syntax! @user88 you will get an error!